# There are no ebuilds to satisfy

Tags: gentoo, emerge, portage

So, I want to install the vimb browser from a Gentoo overlay called 'booboo'. I added the overlay with layman and ran `emerge vimb`. This is what I get:

```
emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy ">=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.5.0:2".
(dependency required by "www-client/vimb-2.10::booboo[-gtk3]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "vimb" [argument])
```

Ideas?

Thank you!

PS: Output of `emerge -s webkit-gtk`:

````
net-libs/webkit-gtk
Latest version available: 2.28.4
Latest version installed: 2.28.3
Size of files: 20,923 KiB
Homepage:      https://www.webkitgtk.org
Description:   Open source web browser engine
License:       LGPL-2+ BSD```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebuild for `vimb` in overlay you are mentioning wasn't updated for 5 years and it depends on packages, that no longer exists in the official portage tree.

Notice it depends on `>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.5.0:2` which specifies slot 2 (`:2` at the end), but in the [official tree](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/net-libs/webkit-gtk), there is only slot 4.

If it helps you, I put an updated [.ebuild](https://github.com/BlueManCZ/edgets/blob/master/www-client/vimb/vimb-3.6.0.ebuild) into my [overlay](https://github.com/BlueManCZ/edgets).